# Modifying a partitioned table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

After partitioning a table i created, i tried modifying the table by altering the partition function, by using this sql statement:

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME p_scheme_RIGHT NEXT USED FILEG7;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION p_funtn_pid() SPLIT RANGE('2018-01-O1 00:00:00.000000');
```

This action returned an error message:

```
Could not implicitly convert range values type specified at ordinal 1 to partition function parameter type.
```